# Receiving `MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms`

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I'm trying to store data to my MongoDB server, I wanted started of by trying to add a User data when a new user joins a server, but I keep getting buffered timeout. I've been looking for a solution for a whole day and nothing is working.

Here are some information:

I have whitelisted my ip in the atlas:

My Atlas Network Access

[image: 1]

The connection code being used:

```js
mongoose.connect(dbUrl, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
    })
    .then(() => console.log("Database connected!")).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

My User Model:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userID: { type: String },
  guildID: { type: String },
  xp: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  level: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  balance: {type: Number, default: 0},
  banned: {type: Boolean, default: false},
  muted: {type: Boolean, default: false},
  messages: {type: Number, default: 0},
  lastUpdated: { type: Date, default: new Date() },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

My Mongo Connection

```
MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>!@personalcluster.rav32vj.mongodb.net/KingsData?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

On User Join

```
const client = require('../index.js')
const levels = require('../models/Users')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config()

client.on('guildMemberAdd', async (member) => {
    const newUser = new levels({
        userID: member.id,
        guildID: process.env.GUILDID
    });
      
    await newUser.save().catch(e => console.log(`Failed to create user: ${e}`))
})
```

Comment: This error occurs when mongoose fails to connect mongodb. keep that in mind mongoose doesn't throw error immediately, it will buffer all queries 10 sec if it could not connect to database.
So try connecting to database using `mongo` shell and make sure URI is correct & working.

Comment: As @bogdanoff said, sometimes if mongoose throws an error like this, its sometimes your connection. *internet connections*